# Sqlite Browser NOT opening on Centos 6.5

Tags: centos, sqlite

When I try to open an .exe file in centOS (Release 6.5) by double clicking, it is not opening. I am creating an app which requires databases. I cannot check whether the data has gone in database or not because of this.I think may be some silly settings are blocking it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: you can't run `.exe` file on centos without `wine` http://www.winehq.org/

Comment: What .exe file? Where did you get it? If this is really a Windows executable, such files don't run natively on non-Windows operating systems. Please [edit] and clarify exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You might try the Linux version of the software instead of the Windows version. The project website has [the source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/files/), and I found a [tutorial](http://blog.randell.ph/2009/07/26/install-sqlite-database-browser-on-fedora/) that should work for CentOS 6.5. Otherwise, to run a Windows executable on a non-Windows O/S, you might have success using [WINE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29).

Or, there are other GUI database browsers like [Valentia](http://www.valentina-db.com/en/valentina-studio-overview). You want the RPM package for use with CentOS.

Comment: I tried the source and even the tutorial you provided earlier. But i cannot find any .sh file inside the folder after extracting it. And in tutorials I end up at qmake step.

Comment: Valentina is not opening the .db file. It is set for .sqlite file i suppose.